# EclipseLink and H2

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, h2

I trying to use EclipseLink JPA provider with H2 DBMS in Eclipse IDE.

When I create a new JPA project and fill the data (URL="jdbc:h2:~/test",Username="user",password="") connection type : resource local (I'm using the embedded mode) 
I get 2 odd things :

1. when I try to create Entities from table I get a blank table list
2. I get an error message near @Entity notation saying that "catalog User can't be resolved for entity e1" or "Schema User can't be resolved for entity e1" depending on keeping the default value for catalog or changing it upon project creation where User is the database user name

The database already contains tables using the h2 console in Firefox

What is the cause of these problems and how can I solve it and do you have any page or book that can help with persistence.xml file (other than the oracle official web site)?

Comment: The database URL looks wrong: a slash is missing. It should be `jdbc:h2:~/test`.

Comment: Sorry about that . It's an error while typing here.
By the way this still works and create new database :)

Comment: OK. This is important because `jdbc:h2:~/test` is a database in the current user home directory, and `jdbc:h2:~test` is a database in the current working directory (where you started the application), with the file name `~test`.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink doesn't create the database tables for you, unless you explicitely tell it to do so.

The way to do that is described in [the documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL)

> EclipseLink can be used to automatically generate the tables and database schema for a persistence unit. This is done through the "eclipselink.ddl-generation" persistence unit property, set to either "create-tables" or "drop-and-create-tables". The tables and constraints will be generated for all of the classes defined in that persistence unit.

Comment: I have not said anything about creating tables from entities I'm talking about creating Entities from tables

Comment: And how would the H2 database contain any table if you never create them? Mind reading? Black magic?

Comment: The database already contains tables,I created them using its console in firefox

Comment: The URL jdbc:h2:~/test is an URL for a database file relative to the current directory of your app. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#embedded_databases. So you're probably not connecting to the same database as the one in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to set the right catalog when creating the JPA Project and then every thing worked splendidly